# Performing Tobit Regression in Mathematica by Maximum LogLikelihood

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting

I am trying to estimate a tobit model by maximum likelihood method in Mathematica. I can not find the build-in function. So I try to perform it manually.
Here is the log likelihood function of Tobit model on wiki.
\begin{aligned}
\log \mathcal{L}(\beta, \sigma) & =\sum_{j=1}^n I\left(y_j\right) \log \left(\frac{1}{\sigma} \varphi\left(\frac{y_j-X_j \beta}{\sigma}\right)\right)+\left(1-I\left(y_j\right)\right) \log \left(1-\Phi\left(\frac{X_j \beta-y_L}{\sigma}\right)\right) \\
& =\sum_{y_j>y_L} \log \left(\frac{1}{\sigma} \varphi\left(\frac{y_j-X_j \beta}{\sigma}\right)\right)+\sum_{y_j=y_L} \log \left(\Phi\left(\frac{y_L-X_j \beta}{\sigma}\right)\right)
\end{aligned}

$\Phi$ is the standard normal CDF. $\varphi$ is the standard normal PDF. My model is left censored at 0.

I tried

```
FindMaximum[{LogLikelihood[NormalDistribution[], (yjVector - Vecbeta.X1Matrix)/Sigma] + n*Log[1/Sigma] + Total[Log[CDF[NormalDistribution[], (yLVector - Vecbeta.X2Matrix)/Sigma]]],Sigma > 0},Join[{Sigma},Vecbeta]]
```

and

```
FindMaximum[{Total[Table[LogLikelihood[CensoredDistribution[{0,inf},NormalDistribution[(Vecbeta.XMatrix)[[n]],Sigma]],{yVector[[n]]}],{n,1,M}]],Sigma > 0},Join[{Sigma},Vecbeta]]
```

Both of them give [image].

[image]

It seems when Mathematica adjusts the vector of $\beta$ and $\sigma$ to evaluate $\sum_{y_j=y_L} \log \left(\Phi\left(\frac{y_L-X_j \beta}{\sigma}\right)\right)$, it is very easy for it to search for some values of $\beta$ and $\sigma$ which make $\Phi\left(\frac{y_L-X_j \beta}{\sigma}\right)$ too close to 0 and makes $ \log \left(\Phi\left(\frac{y_L-X_j \beta}{\sigma}\right)\right)$ indeterminate.

With the same model, I use STATA and it offers some estimator. If I set initial values in FindMaximum near to the STATA estimator,

```
FindMaximum[..., {{beta1, 1.5},{beta2, 1.9},{beta3, 0.01},{beta4, -0.048},{beta5, 97.},{Sigma, 0.95}}]
```

Mathematica works fine and gives the same estimator as STATA.

Any tricks I should play here to avoid this problem? Or is there a more sophisticated  way for me to perform a Tobit in mathematica?

Comment: You've determined how to avoid the problem: use good starting values as the default starting values are all 1.  You could try using regular linear regression to get starting values.

Comment: Note that STATA has a specific function for Tobit regression (unlike *Mathematica*) and so must have some approach to setting starting values.  I could not find anything in STATA's documentation but I would guess that regular linear regression is used to find starting values.